# Call Spring Boot Application Property From Other Property Or Java VM Option

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a property like below in Spring Boot **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?serverTimezone=UTC&connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=30000
```

In here, I want to give "**connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=30000**" arguments with other properties like:

```
db.myprops=connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?serverTimezone=UTC&{db.myprops}
```

How can I handle it or Is there a specific properties in Spring Boot for connectTimeout and socketTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

To call it as other property in Spring-Boot Configuration:

```
spring.application.property.1=property1
spring.application.property.2=property2${spring.application.property.1}
```

Then we can call it from Java environment to customize it like below:

```
java -Dspring.application.property.1=custom -jar ../*.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use JPA spring uses Hikari as the underlying database connection pool

```
//example configuration
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
```

[Hikari configuration knobs](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Comment: Thanks @thomas but hikari doesn't have property for socket timeout.